# Titanium consuming REST POST Service, input is empty when server receives request

Tags: javascript, java, rest, titanium, wildfly

I have a titanium app, and I'm trying to consume a REST Service exposed on Wildfly 8.x and developed on Java using RESTEasy.
I managed to make the request reach my wildfly server, but when  I check inside the debug what's the method receiving as input, it's an empty String.
Also, it is important to note that the WebService receives a String because I'm using a JSon converting library that I did myself, and it receives a JSon as a String.

This is the javascript Titanium code:

```js
var pilotoUsuarioDTO =
    {
     "pilotoUsuariosDTO":
     {
      "idUsu":"null",
      "idPilotoFacultad": "null",
      "usuNom": "null",
      "usuLog": usuario,
      "usuCon": contrasena,
      "usuTip": "null"
      }
    };
 
 var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient(onload = function()
  {
   Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);
   respuesta = responseText;
  });
  
 xhr.open('POST','http://10.0.2.2:8081/JAXRS-Ometeus/rs/LoggeoOmeteus/loggear');
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
 xhr.send(JSON.stringify(pilotoUsuarioDTO));
```

This how I exposed the service:

```js
 @POST
 @Path("/loggear")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public String encontrarUsuario(String usuarioABuscarDTO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, closed and opened again Appcelerator studio